# jQuery - One trigger per each certain scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

This is little hard to explain. I have issue with infinite scroll function. When I scroll down my content, on certain scroll position I call one function to load my content on page. Here is that function:

```
var page = 1,
    total = 10; // example
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var search = $(document).scrollTop(),
        position = ($(document).height() - (($(".footer").height() * 2) - 50) - $(".page-heading").height() - $(".page-footer").height() - $(".navbar-toalc").height());
    if (search > position && page <= total) {
        triggerLoad(page);
        console.log(page);
        page++;
    }
});
```

When i get certain scroll point, I trigger function `triggerLoad()` where is function for ajax call and hide button on last page. That part work nice.

**PROBLEM:**

Function above immediately made loop of all pages. I need something to delay that loop until load new content, measure the page and waiting until I scroll on new position. Measuremant works fine but until load content I have arround 8 scroll calls and that made a loop.

Comment: use a global variable as a flag, ie `var searching = false;` in your if then `if(!searching && search > ...`. inside your `if` set it to `true`. then in your ajax `success` after you add the content reset it to `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very easy way is to "check" if you are already executing the **triggerLoad**

For example with a class to the page which says it's loading, or maybe using a boolean variable as true while loading and then reset at false with a callback function to the ajax complete

```
var page = 1,
    total = 10,  // example 
    isLoading = false;     // <<-------

$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var search = $(document).scrollTop(),
        position = ($(document).height() - (($(".footer").height() * 2) - 50) - $(".page-heading").height() - $(".page-footer").height() - $(".navbar-toalc").height());
    if (search > position && page <= total && isLoading === false) {
        isLoading = true;  
        triggerLoad(page, function(){ isLoading = false; });
        console.log(page);
        page++;
    }
});
```

Remember to add the callback function as complete callback of your ajax

```
function triggerLoad(_page, _callback){
    // ...

    $.ajax({
        // ...
        complete: _callback
    });

    // ...
}
```

it's not a very clean solution but should work fine

Comment: Thanks! I realy forgot about callback.